# Confusing TS error on store update method

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

The error is "Argument of type '(oldData: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Trade[]'.ts"
However, if I hover over "update" it gives: "update: (value: Trade[]) => void", which seems fine to me.

```
export const trades: Writable<Trade[]> = writable([] as Trade[], function start(update) {
    streamer.on("polyTrades", (trades: Trade[]) => {

        update((oldData) => {
            const updateData = [ ...oldData, ...trades ]
            return updateData
        })
    })

    return function stop() {
        streamer.off("polyTrades")
    }
})
```

I've tried assigning a type to "oldData" but that doesn't work either. Seems like maybe a Svelte thing. Is there a reasonably simple way of fixing this without using //@ts-ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to `start` is a `set` function. It does not take a callback, just the new value.

```js
writable(value?: any, start?: (set: (value: any) => void) => () => void)
```

> If a function is passed as the second argument, it will be called when the number of subscribers goes from zero to one (but not from one to two, etc). That function will be passed a `set` function which changes the value of the store. It must return a `stop` function that is called when the subscriber count goes from one to zero.

([Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable))

If you need the previous value, you might be able to just use `trades.update` directly.